# mongoengine bulk upsert a batch of record?

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine, upsert

I want to `upsert(update or insert) a list of record`, in fact I know that mongodb support `bulk` operation since mongodb3.0.

I want to know whether `mongoengine` support `bulk upsert operation` in `mongoengine (0.10.0)`.

if not, I want to know how to `upsert` a list of record, I know `mongoengine` support `insert` batch like this:

```
class User(Document):
    username = StringField(required=True)
    password = StringFiedl(required=True)
    meta = {'db_alias': 'user_info', 'collection': 'user', 
             'indexes': [{'fields': ['username'], 'unique': True}]
           }

def save_users(self, users):
    Users.objects.insert(users) # raise mongoengine.errors.NotUniqueError
```

Comment: @AndreL in fact the last one is my code

Comment: @AndreL maybe the simple schema make you understand me, I have a unique key `username`, and I just want to insert the user or update the user if user exist.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can actually use the [bulk operations API](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk/) directly by accessing the underlying collection object from the pymongo driver MongoEngine uses. MongoDB itself has supported bulk operations since version 2.6. There are newer methods to access these since v3 of the pymongo driver, but the basic methods have been around since the corresponding driver update to the 2.6 Server version ( pymongo 2.7 ).

To get this with MongoEngine you can call the undocumented `._get_collection()` from your class to return the [collection](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html) object:

```
bulk = Users._get_collection().initialize_ordered_bulk_op()

for user in users:  # where users is a list of dicts containing data to work on
    bulk.find({ "matchField": user['matchField'] }).upsert().replace_one(user)

bulk.execute()
```

Or any other usage of [bulk methods](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/bulk.html#pymongo.bulk.BulkOperationBuilder) such as `.update_one()` which you probably want. And [`.upsert()`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/bulk.html#pymongo.bulk.BulkWriteOperation.upsert) is a chained method that modifies such update statements.

You are working with raw python objects here as there is no direct equivalent in MongoEngine itself. But you can use the operations by accessing the methods from the underlying driver

Comment: 'Collection' object is not callable. If you meant to call the 'inititalize_ordered_bulk_op' method on a 'Collection' object it is failing because no such method exists.

Comment: @roger Oops. Typo! Should be `initialize_ordered_bulk_op()`

Comment: @thanks a lot, my stupid! I have found a way to fix `raw python objects` problem, `Mongoengine Document` has a method `to_mongo()` translate to dict, `bulk.find({ "matchField": user['matchField'] }).upsert().replace_one(user.to_mongo())`

Comment: @roger I wasn't viewing it as a problem as the chances are for most people that the data is a raw object before they instantiate to a class, and yes I was already aware of `to_mongo()`. My point was basically to say that in a "bulk" situation that since you are bypassing the MongoEngine wrappers to store anyway, it seems logical to bypass the overhead of instantiating data to a class, Anyhow, now you know about an undocumented method and the usage of bulk API methods via pymongo.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`mongo.collection.Collection.bulk_write`](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.bulk_write):

```
operations = [
    pymongo.ReplaceOne({'username': user. username}, user.to_mongo(), upsert=True)
    for user in users
]
result = User._get_collection().bulk_write(operations)
```